# What is the group $\langle U, * \rangle$ where $U$ is the set of roots of unity and * is normal multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble understanding my textbook in this regard. Everything else seems to make sense, such as the group $\langle \mathbb{Z}_{1000}, + \rangle$ to list an example.

In the text, it is stated that $\langle U, * \rangle$ contains two elements that are their own inverse (namely, $-1$ and $1$), but what does that mean in this scope? I am having a tough time picturing it. Sure, $1*1 = 1$ and $-1 * -1 = 1$, but is that what they're getting at? Doesn't $U$ have some relation to the unit circle, that I should be factoring in? I understand $\langle U_4, * \rangle$ having four solutions to $z^4 = 1$, but where does the $U$ versus $U_4$ come in similarly? I'm just having a tough time comprehending $U$ and would love for some insight into it.

Comment: What is $U$ ? Is it the set of roots of unity ?

Comment: I apologize. Yes. I believe that would be it. I know $U_n$ would be the set of nth roots of unity, hence I would assume $U$ to be the set of all roots of unity.

Comment: Is $*$ supposed to be the normal multiplication? Normally if you mean that, you'd write $\cdot$ or $\times$; $*$ usually hints at a special multiplication which is different from the normal one.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't know how to create the dot in latex, so I substituted it with *. It is indeed normal multiplication. Just clarified in the title.

Comment: The dot is created with \cdot.

Comment: @David I've provided an answer to your question below. If you don't think it answers your question, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guide**: The main crux of the answer to your question begins with the bold words "**The main point is outlined** ...". Nevertheless, I recommend carefully reading the material up to this point, in particular ***Exercises 1 and 2*** below, because if you understand the solutions to those ***Exercises***, then I think you will have an answer to your question.

Let $(U,\ast)$ denote the multiplicative group consisting of all roots of unity in $(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\cdot)$ (the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers). In words, $U$ consists of all (necessarily non-zero) complex numbers $z$ such that $z^n=1$ for *some* natural number $n\geq 1$.

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $(U,\ast)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\cdot)$. (Note that I have used $\ast$ and $\cdot$ to indicate the multiplications on $U$ and $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, respectively. The reason is that $\ast:U\times U\to U$ and $\cdot:\mathbb{C}^{\times}\times \mathbb{C}^{\times}\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ are different functions because they have different domains. Essentially, one component of this exercise asks you to verify that the function $\ast$ is the restriction of the function $\cdot$; but this should be obvious.)

Of course, we also have groups $(U_n,\ast)$ for all natural numbers $n\geq 1$. (I denote the multiplications on all of these groups by the same symbol; technically, this is an abuse of notation as I explained above but this should not cause any confusion.) In words, $U_n$ consists of all (necessarily non-zero) complex numbers $z$ such that $z^n=1$.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that $(U_n,\ast)$ is a subgroup of $(U,\ast)$ for all natural numbers $n\geq 1$. By transitivity of the relation "is a subgroup of", it follows from ***Exercise 1*** that $(U_n,\ast)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\cdot)$.

**The main point is outlined in the form of the following Exercise**:

***Exercise 3***: Prove that *as sets* $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$ but that this is *not* an ascending union, i.e., $U_n\not\subseteq U_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$. For which $n,m\geq 1$ is it true that $U_n\subseteq U_m$?

In fact, we have more information than is strictly contained in ***Exercise 3***; the $U_n$'s are all *groups* and *their union is also a group*. What does this mean/imply? The main thing relevant to your question is that every element $z\in U$ is an element of $U_n$ for some $n$ and, in this case, the element $z^{-1}\in U$ will also be an element of $U_n$. (If this is not obvious, prove it! It's formally a consequence of ***Exercise 2***; that $U_n$ is a subgroup of $U$.)

Similarly, if $z\in U$, then the inverse of $z$ in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is also an element of $U$. (Again, because formally $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$!)

***Exercise 4***: Let $S$ and $T$ be the sets of elements in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $U$, respectively, consisting of those elements equal to their own inverses. Prove that $S\cap U=T$.

***Exercise 5***: What is $S$? Does that answer your question in conjunction with ***Exercise 4***?

The role of the group $(\mathbb{C}^{\times},\cdot)$ in this situation can also be played by the **circle group** $(\mathbb{S}^{1},\cdot)$ consisting of all complex numbers $z$ with $\left|z\right|=1$. $U$ is a subgroup of the circle group and the circle group is, in turn, a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting. To quickly delve into "In the text, it is stated that ⟨U,*⟩ contains two elements that are their own inverse (namely, −1 and 1), but what does that mean in this scope?" and ensure I get it, could you quickly go through the computation of that. Namely, -1 being it's own inverse.

Comment: @David The inverse of $-1$ as an element of the group $U$ is equal to the inverse of $-1$ as an element of the group $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. (Formally, this is because $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.) Of course, the inverse of $-1$ in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is equal to itself because we know how to multiply non-zero complex numbers and we know that $(-1)(-1)=1$. Here, $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ denotes the multiplicative group consisting of all non-zero complex numbers as in my answer above. The key point is that $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ so you can do computations ...

Comment: @David ... with elements of $U$ by doing the computations in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. (... And of course, you'll still get elements in $U$ if you do such computations because $U$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$; I can't emphasise this point enough!) Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok, I was just verifying. Thanks!

Comment: @David Your welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The set $U$ of unit roots is the set of all numbers $z$ so that $z^n=1$ for some positive $n\in \mathbb N$. Equivalently, it is the set of all numbers $\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm iq}$ where $q$ is a rational number, Proof: Be $q=m/n$, then $(\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm iq})^n = \mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm inq} = \mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm im}=1$.

From that, we can see that $U$ is a dense subset of the unit circle.

Also we can see that $\langle U,\cdot\rangle$ is closed under multiplication by noting that $\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm iq}\cdot\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ir} = \mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i(q+r)}$. Clearly $q+r$ is also rational.

Similarly we can prove that it is a group by noting that the multiplicative inverse on $U$ maps on the additive inverse (negative) on $\mathbb Q$. Associativity and neutral element are obvious. Indeed, it is an abelian group.

It is also not hard to see this way that $U$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Clearly $U_n\subset U$ for all $n$. Since $U_n$ is a group by itself, it is a subgroup of $U$. Indeed, $U$ is the union of all $U_n$.